# Sleeping in work place

Tags: work-environment

Is it bad thing to sleep in cubicle for 20-30 minutes during working hours when I'm not feeling well?

There is a dormitory but because of more work pressure I can't go to it and also I can't take leave because of a tight schedule.

Comment: I think this is going to be rather too localised to your specific environment to answer. I think most people would simply answer "Oh my gosh, yes it's bad to sleep at your desk at work" but the fact that your environment includes a dormitory and you're working though illness (why not just take time off to recover?) kinda skews things a bit.

Comment: related: [How can I meditate while sitting at my desk in the office without looking sleepy?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/22105/how-can-i-meditate-while-sitting-at-my-desk-in-the-office-without-looking-sleepy)

Comment: There is a dormitory makes it sound like this company is closely watching what its employees are doing. Are there other break times? Do they clock you going to the bathroom?